# How to migrate user, groups,etc a new samba PDC

Tags: ubuntu, centos, samba, domain-controller

Currently I have a machine running CentOS 5.8 and Samba configured as PDC.

I'm changing the CentOS operating system to Ubuntu, a group of servers, PDC is only to change, but I have some doubts. I do not know how to migrate user data (passwords, groups, etc) to the new PDC

Answer (score 0):

You can Install the new box as a bdc and sync the accounts. Then promote it to pdc and bring down the old pdc.

We used this procedure a few times and it worked fine. You can also rsync the accounts and settings to the new machine manually.

Comment: have some tutorial to follow personally I never installed a PDC